# How can I delete my accounts and posts?

Tags: discussion

I would like to delete all my Stack Exchange accounts. How can I do this?

Is it also possible to remove all my questions associated with those accounts (three accounts in total)?

I'm not sure where to ask this question, sorry if it is in the wrong place.

Comment: Questions about Stack Exchange itself should be posted on Meta; this one will be migrated there automatically. (It's most likely that you will not be able to have your contributions deleted; see [this answer on Stack Overflow Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92761/49849) among others.)

Comment: I don't think they will delete your questions, just your account and it's association with said questions. Like the two ppl on this question: http://superuser.com/questions/65321/laptop-gets-really-hot-then-turns-off-suspect-it-is-overheating-how-can-i-redu

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: Why do you so suddenly want to do this? Given that your activity is very valid, it almost sounds like someone else used your computer to ask this. Please note that your questions and answers won't be deleted as to preserve useful Q&A posts, [as I see that you have some nice posts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/741875/craig?tab=questions&sort=votes)...

Comment: Note that in accordance with [CC](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) deleting an account retains the content with identity anonymised

Answer (score 4):

There is a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/155320) over at meta.stackoverflow that can answer this for you.

Bear in mind (as Jeff says in the comments) you'll need to do this for every site you have an account on.

I believe this deletes the account, but *not* the posts. You've licensed them to the site under CC-Wiki. Your username will be obscured.

> If your account has never voted or posted a question or answer you
>   should see a self-delete option on your user page.
>
> However, if your account *has* voted or posted, do the following:
>
> 1. **Edit the "about me" field in your profile to say "please delete me"** so we can confirm your ownership of the account.
> 2. **Obtain your user page URL or numeric user ID**. This is linked from the top of every page of the site when you are logged in.
> 3. **Email the support address linked at the bottom of every web page** on the site. Where it says "contact us", click that. In your
>      email, you **MUST** include your user page URL or user ID so we can
>      find your account.
>
> Also of note, we automatically cull old inactive accounts as
>   documented here:
>
> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: Also note you can SYNC your profile from the about me editing, and it will go across all sites.